# Hide anniversary notice bar

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to hide the anniversary celebratory notice? I'm super excited for SuperUser's birthday, and was really happy to see that, but now that I know, it's a little bit distracting having it up there everywhere I go.

P.s. Happy Birthday SuperUser! ;)

Answer (score 10):

Use a [user script](http://files.whitequark.org/hide-anniversary.user.js)?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name      Hide the anniversary bar on SuperUser
// @namespace http://whitequark.org/greasemonkey
// @include   http://superuser.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var bar = document.getElementById('system-message');
if(bar.textContent.indexOf('anniversary') != -1)
  bar.parentNode.removeChild(bar);
```

Comment: Ah cool, indirectly I understand how user scripts work under Google Chrome now, thank you... ^^

Comment: Hmm, that looks nifty, and I do use Chrome frequently, but it would be nice to have an easier solution, and I'm sure other users (who might not be reading meta) would appreciate an easy way, too.

Answer (score 3):

We *could* insert it as a message in everyone's message queue so it would be dismissable.. but the 90% of traffic that is anonymous (unregistered, no account) users would never see it then.

Comment: Can you just add a `[hide]` button which will set a cookie and hide that particular message?

Comment: I rather like whitequark's suggestion, or some similar such implementation. Or perhaps it could be a combination of the style of how user messages and the "Are you new here? See the FAQ" bar that unregistered users get -- show it to all users, and remember whether they've closed it using a session-only cookie for unregistered users but remember it as an account setting for registered users?